# Not able to connect to accounts.google.com anymore

Tags: google-app-engine

Last week we are getting errors from `accounts.google.com`. 
How can we fix the problem? We use GAE standard environment with python 2.7 and requests 2.18+

We are getting this one during about 5 days:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='accounts.google.com',
port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /o/oauth2/token 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object
at 0xfaa13790: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110]
connection timed out',))
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet how you try to establish connection?

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using urllib3.  Make sure you have ssl enabled in your `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

GAE deleted ssl version 2.7 recently.